# the legend categories in the graph itself and not on the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I want a graph where the "vacc_status_broad" variable categories show in the graph itself and not just on the legend.

[image: desired image]

this is my code

```r
sur %>% 
  filter(species_broad == "Dog")%>%
  add_count(species_broad) %>%
  mutate(y_species_broad = 
           reorder(
             factor(paste0(species_broad, "\n", "(n = ", n, ")")),
             as.numeric(species_broad)
           )) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping=aes(y= y_species_broad, fill=vacc_status_broad)) + 
  geom_bar(colour="black" , position = "fill")+
  scale_x_continuous (labels=c("0","25%","50%","75%","100%"))  +
  labs (x="Proportion of responses",y="Animal species")+ 
  ggtitle ("Type of exposure")
```

My data via dput:

```
structure(list(species_broad = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), levels = c("Dog", 
"Cat", "Rat/rodent", "Monkey", "Cattle"), class = "factor"), 
    vacc_status_broad = c("Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Vaccinated", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Vaccinated", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Vaccinated", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Vaccinated", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Vaccinated", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Vaccinated", "Vaccinated", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Vaccinated", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Vaccinated", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Vaccinated", "Vaccinated", "Vaccinated", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", 
    "Not vaccinated / Unknown status", "Not vaccinated / Unknown status"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please let me know how I can get the categories in the graph itself?

Comment: The "I want this" image is not in the question, please [edit] your question and add it. It won't show automatically for you, it will show as a link, often one of us will make it more visible in the question once you've added it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sur %>% 
  filter(species_broad == "Dog")%>%
  add_count(species_broad) %>%
  mutate(y_species_broad = 
           reorder(
             factor(paste0(species_broad, "\n", "(n = ", n, ")")),
             as.numeric(species_broad)
           )) %>% 
  
  count(y_species_broad, vacc_status_broad) %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, y_species_broad, fill = vacc_status_broad, label = vacc_status_broad)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
  geom_text(position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  scale_x_continuous (labels=c("0","25%","50%","75%","100%"))  +
  labs (x="Proportion of responses",y="Animal species")+ 
  ggtitle ("Type of exposure")
```

[image]